# Ruby on Rails - getting user input from custom form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, input, user-input

I have two tables `Question` and `Answer` where in the Question model there is a line that defines the association between the two tables as `has_many Answer` and in Answer model: `belongs_to Question`.

In `Questions` table I have the following columns: `id`, `title`, `subtitle` and `question_type`.

In `Answers` table I just have two columns: `question_id` and `text`

I setup the form in _form.html.erb such that it will get a predefined question set (so for example, question id 1,2,5,6,11). Further, the form will just according to that set to dynamically create what is needed for the form. The following code is what I have for doing such:

(Where as `set` is an Array that stores the predefined questions set and the answers associating with the question. Each question is an OpenStruct that stores all the relevant information for the corresponding question)

```
<% field_names = Array.new %>
<% set.each do |question| %>
    <%= f.label question.question %>
    <%= f.label question.question_subtitle %>
    <% case question.question_type %>
        <% when "check box" %>
            <%= f.label question.question_type %>
            <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
                <%= check_box_tag(answer.answer_id) %>
                <%= label_tag(question.id, answer.text) %>
                <%
                   field_names.append(params[answer.answer_id])
                %>
            <% end %>

        <% when "text field" %>
            <%= f.label question.question_type %>
            <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
                <%= answer.text %>
                <%= text_field(question.question_id, answer.answer_id) %>
                <%
                   s = ((question.question_id).to_s + "[" + (answer.answer_id).to_s + "]")
                   field_names.append(params[s])
                %>
            <% end %>

        <% when "scale" %>
            <%= f.label question.question_type %>
            <%
               range = Array.new
               question.answers.each do |answer|
                 range.append(answer.text)
               end
               field_names.append(params[question.answers[0].answer_id])
            %>
            <%= select_tag(question.answers[0].answer_id, options_for_select(range[0]..range[1])) %>
    <% end %>
    <br/>
<% end %>
```

Now the question is just that when I click the submit button, how will I be able to get all the user inputs in the form according to the question ID?

I am thinking of cases where there are multiple questions of the same types and multiple answer fields for one question. Or is there a better way than this that will also achieve what I want?

EDIT: Here is the HTML code generated by the above ruby embedded code, if it helps.

```
    <label for="tracker_question 1">Question 1</label>
    <label for="tracker_question 1 Subtitle">Question 1 subtitle</label>
        <label for="tracker_check box">Check box</label>
            <input id="1" name="1" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            <label>answer 1-1</label>
            <input id="2" name="2" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            <label>answer 1-2</label>

    <br/>
    <label for="tracker_question 2">Question 2</label>
    <label for="tracker_question 2 Subtitle">Question 2 subtitle</label>
        <label for="tracker_text field">Text field</label>
            answer 2-1
            <input id="11_3" name="11[3]" size="30" type="text" />
            answer 2-2
            <input id="11_4" name="11[4]" size="30" type="text" />

    <br/>
    <label for="tracker_question 3">Question 3</label>
    <label for="tracker_question 3 Subtitle">Question 3 subtitle</label>
        <label for="tracker_scale">Scale</label>
        <select id="5" name="5">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
                  <option value="6">6</option>
                  <option value="7">7</option>
                  <option value="8">8</option>
                  <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
```

EDIT:

I changed the code a bit so that now each field is using a different name instead of all were using the same name if they have the same property. But the name depends on the answer id and if it is text field then it will be both answer id and question id.

This way, I'm thinking that, maybe I can just use the `before_save` redirection to access these fields since it generates a hash like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"DgdKpdecD+jmq1EvAIPxzjFxHGOUkJXoE10VpCBtxqU=",
"tracker"=>{"patient_id"=>"1"},
"1"=>"1",
"11"=>{"3"=>"test1",
"4"=>"test2"},
"5"=>"6",
"commit"=>"Create Tracker"}
```

Thus, I made another variable called `field_names` to get the field names but I can't seem to get working as the way I want it to. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain better what you are thinking about? maybe by a pseudo code example.

Answer (score 0):

You have a multiple resources form. As far as I understand, you want to save several answers. I suppose this because you are rendering all answers for the question, so I suppose you are NOT in the part where questions and answers are being created.

If that's the case, I would create a model that saves this information, is difficult to name it:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

and a model to group these items:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items

  attr_accessible :items_attributes
end
```

You have not mentioned `user` though.

Then my form would be something like:

```
<%= form_for @test do |test| %>

  <%= test.fields_for :items do |item|  %>
    <%# Render question ----> your code %>

    <%= item.hidden_field :question_id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Your controller:

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @test = Test.new question_ids: params[:question_ids]
  end

  def create
    @test = Test.new params[:test]

    if @test.save
      # success
    else
      # fail
    end
  end
end
```

Note that you will send `params[:question_ids]` to build a form. For that to work:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  attr_accessible :question_ids
```

Maybe I missed the entire point of the question.